# Entity Framework - SqlQuery with List<> of parameters

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am trying to query the db with an IN clause using EF:

```
List<int> ids = new List<int> {1,2,3,4....20};
string sql = GetSql(ids);
//sql is "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Id in (@p0, @p1, @p2 ... @p19)"
var res = db.Set<Student>().SqlQuery(sql, ids);
```

But I get the following exception :

**No mapping exists from object type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int64, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] to a known managed provider native type.**

Comment: This may not be what the issue is, but I have a really strong feeling that the sql query is using the literal object as a parameter and not what is inside the object.

If you don't mind, can you please post your GetSql method and any other custom method calls that are made here.

Comment: I agree, this it not a duplicate. The solution I found using parameters is by building an array of SqlParameter: SqlParameter[] parameters. It has to be an array. Using a list produced the same error as above. Code: SqlParameter[] parameters = ids.Select((r, i) => new SqlParameter($"@ManualRead{i}", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = r }).ToArray();

            string parameterNames = string.Join(",", parameters.Select(x => x.ParameterName)); ---- " where Id IN ({parameterNames})"; --- Context.Database.SqlQuery<Student>(cmd, parameters);

Answer (score 2):

I am handling it in a clause like this:

```
List<int> ids = new List<int> { 1,2,3 };
db.Set<Student>().Where(r => ids.Contains(r.ID));
```

UPDATE:

You do as follows (I have not tested by myself but it should do your job):

```
public List<CustomObject> ExecuteCustomQuery(List<int> items)
{
    var ids = string.Join(",", 
                          items.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());
                          
    string query = "SELECT Column1, Column1 FROM TABLE1 where id in (" + ids + ")";
    
    return dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<CustomObject>(query).ToList();
}
```

`CustomObject` has two properties that match the returning columns of the `SELECT` statement.

Let me know how did you go. Thanks.

Comment: This might not be efficient as stated in several questions I saw here in SO.

Comment: You might want to check with the profiler that it is still calling one time with this where clause for me  INNER JOIN [dbo].[transactions] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent7].[ID] = [Extent8].[RequestID]
        WHERE [Extent7].[ID] IN (1, 2)) AS [UnionAll3]

Comment: But what can I do if the table I am querying is not in the EF model ?

Comment: Please see my updated reply above.

Comment: But now I am open to SQL injections. I want to use parameters.

Comment: You can a manual check for sql inject. Otherwise, you can loop through id and make sql params, as sugggested in another answer.

Comment: You are not open to SQL injection from a typed list of integers.

Comment: string.Join() takes ienumerable<int> just fine, as-is.  Don't need to cast to string first.

Comment: i like to use prams also to be able to reuse the command

Comment: In Sql Server, this approach can easily ruin your query cache. Parameters are always a better choice.